# Rewrite SQL to JOINS instead of subqueries

Tags: sql, query-optimization, derby

I have the following query. It uses three subqueries and is executed very often so I'd like to rewrite the query to a `JOIN`. I've attempted to do so though my values are incorrect, does anyone know how I can succesfully rewrite the query?

**Query with subqueries**

```
SELECT  PRODUCT.ID 
FROM    PRODUCT WHERE (
            COALESCE((SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM CORRECTION WHERE CORRECTION.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.ID),0)
            - COALESCE((SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM ORDERROW WHERE ORDERROW.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.ID),0)
            + COALESCE((SELECT SUM(AMOUNTOFPACKAGES * AMOUNTPERPACKAGE) FROM DELIVERYROW WHERE DELIVERYROW.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.ID),0)
            ) > 0
```

**False query with joins**

```
SELECT  PRODUCT.ID
FROM    PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN CORRECTION  ON CORRECTION.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.ID
LEFT JOIN ORDERROW    ON ORDERROW.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.ID
LEFT JOIN DELIVERYROW ON DELIVERYROW.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.ID
GROUP BY PRODUCT.ID
HAVING  (COALESCE(SUM(CORRECTION.AMOUNT),0)
        - COALESCE(SUM(ORDERROW.AMOUNT),0)
        + COALESCE(SUM(DELIVERYROW.AMOUNTOFPACKAGES * DELIVERYROW.AMOUNTPERPACKAGE),0) 
        ) > 0
```

Comment: Have you actually determined that this query is slow? Have you checked indexes (I don't know if there's any profiler for Derby).

Comment: B.t.w. COALESCE is an SQL standard and is available in almost every database.

Comment: @GolezTrol Ok removed the comment on COALESCE. Well, I'm told that subqueries are USUALLY slower than joins and therefor I'd like to compare both queries in benchmarks.

Comment: I understand. The reason why your attempt fails is that each table has a different number of records. That causes a multiplication of some rows (they are displayed in the result multiple times if you wouldn't group the query). Therefor, your results are too high. I will try to wrap this in an answer with an example of how to solve it.

Comment: I've quit my attempt, because of Bill Karwin's answer. I was attempting to do a similar thing, with the same subselects, only by combining them using `union all` and then grouping them again. Depending on the amount and structure of the data either one could be a little faster, but the difference would probably be neglectable and his is much cleaner and more compact.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks anyway for your effort and information!

Comment: Subquery are not "*usually*" slower than joins. And you cannot substitute one for the other. A join might return a completely different result. If a subquery can be replaced with a join, then most modern query optimizers will use the same execution plan anyway. The "usually slower" probably comes from MySQL users as the MySQL query optimizer is known to handle subqueries terribly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, MySQL 5.6 has finally improved subqueries a little bit, but yeah, after 10 years of poor optimization for some cases of subqueries, it's going to be hard for MySQL to redeem itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your rewrite is that there may be many rows for a given product in each of the joined tables, and the total result set will be a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product); it will have as many rows as the number of matched rows in each joined table multiplied together.

You can ensure each joined table has at most one row per product:

```
SELECT  PRODUCT.ID
FROM    PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PRODUCTID, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT 
           FROM CORRECTION GROUP BY PRODUCTID) AS C
  ON C.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PRODUCTID, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT 
           FROM ORDERROW GROUP BY PRODUCTID) AS O
  ON O.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PRODUCTID, SUM(AMOUNTOFPACKAGES * AMOUNTPERPACKAGE) AS AMOUNT 
           FROM DELIVERYROW GROUP BY PRODUCTID) AS D
  ON D.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.ID
WHERE COALESCE(C.AMOUNT,0)
    - COALESCE(O.AMOUNT,0)
    + COALESCE(D.AMOUNT,0) > 0;
```

This solution still technically uses subqueries, but *derived table* subqueries are often less expensive than the *correlated subqueries* you were using.  As always, you can be sure how it will impact your data only by testing.

Comment: However this would still mean I need to use subqueries. You're saying I can't work around the Cartesian products without subqueries?

Comment: Right.  Please read about Cartesian products to understand why.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help! Seems I'd be best of sticking to the original query or by making use of views.

Comment: @Aquillo why don't you want to use subqueries?  This solution is very efficient.  Also, how do you think views will help?

Comment: @Anon It's not that I don't want to use subqueries, I was merely searching for a better way (if there is any). With a view I wouldn't need to calculate the values on every request.

Comment: @Aquillo views don't work that way. It sounds like you are envisioning a 'materialized view' or an 'indexed view', and these are completely different animals whose implementations vary from rdbms to rdbms.  A basic `CREATE VIEW etc, etc` will still recalculate the results every time.

Comment: @Anon, that's true for views in MySQL - they're like an "alias" for a query, and the view's query is executed every time you query the view.  That's different from views in some other RDBMS brands e.g. Oracle, Microsoft, DB2 (and promised in PostgreSQL 9.3).

Comment: @BillKarwin simple views in Oracle and Microsoft operate the same as MySQL...what you are calling a "query alias".  However query optimizers will usually rebuild the execution plan by moving the outer predicates upstream.